# Flask-Sockets keepalive

Tags: python, flask, websocket, flask-sockets

I recently started using `flask-sockets` in my flask application with native WebSocket API as client. I would like to know if there is proper way to send ping requests at certain intervals from the server as keepalive?

When going through the `geventwebsocket` library, I noticed the definition `handle_ping(...)`, but it's never called. Is there a way to determine a ping interval on WS?

I see my sockets dying after a minute and a half inconsistently sometimes.

```py
@socket_blueprint.route('/ws', defaults={'name':''})
def echo_socket(ws):
    while not ws.closed:
        ws_list.append(
        msg = ws.receive()
        ws.send(msg)
```

I could probably spin up a separate thread and send ping opcodes manually every 30 seconds to the clients if I keep them in a list, but I feel like there'd be a better way to handle that..

Answer (score 1):

In `service`, create a `thread` in this thread send some data(any data) to `client`. If `client` already disconnected,after 15s the server will receive closed.
I haven't find any method about ping in gevent `websocket` or `flask-sockets`. So take this method.